# Send text to Text Field

Tags: selenium, xpath, spock, geb

How to send Text in text area field using geb & Spock?

Using just Selenium & the sendKeys I am able to send the text.

But unable to implement using geb spock.

`this[field] = value` - Not working

`element.sendKeys("");` - Working

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately you don't find fortune tellers here, only mere mortals called developers. They are best at answering questions if they can rely on facts, not on guesses. So please be so kind as to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. at least HTML and an executeable Spock test. If you use a page object, please also provide that one. Otherwise there are way too many possible things that can go wrong - and sorry, this is not a quiz show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into the use of Geb Modules, particularly the [Text Area](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#code-textarea-code) module.

Taken from the documentation:

Given the html…

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea name="language"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

It can be used this way…

```
def textarea = $(name: "language").module(Textarea)
textarea.text = "Groovy"

assert textarea.text == "Groovy"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea name="language" id = "id1"/>
    </body>
</html>

=====================================================
//content definition
textarea = { $(#id1") }

//updating value 
textarea.value("your value")

OR

textarea << "your value"
```